# external jar works in java project but getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in spring maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jar, executable-jar

I tried adding an external JAR to an existing Maven project via `Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External JARs...`.

I made all the correct imports in the class file, cleaned the project and all the usual Maven clean and install stuff.

The project runs fine, but when I debug and reach the line which accesses a class from the external JAR I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/xyzPath] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: somepath] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: somepath
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:439)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: So have you checked if your external jar is in WEB-INF/lib? Checked your pom.xml if and how dependency was added?

Comment: Maybe you should check in the .m2 itself if the jar was downloaded correctly or not , if not then the dependency in your pom might not have been resolved correctly i.e version is incorrect , you might want to check the central maven or your maven repository itself to see if the jar really exists.

Comment: @GyroGearless Sorry, but I couldn't locate any lib folder under WEB-INF. And being an external jar, what do I need to check in pom. Could you be specific please.

Comment: @fatcook It's an external jar. What dependancy should I add in maven?

Comment: The external jar should be either in your maven repository or lib folder, check [this](http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/) link for details on different ways you can achieve this. Ideally , all your dependencies should be in a central repository which you can manage correctly and have them versioned properly.

Comment: @fatcook Thanks for the link. But, I already got a solution which happens to be point number 2 in your link(dirty solution...lol). I solved it from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm . Why is it a dirty solution?

Comment: @Anup Nair  Because then you are really not using the maven and its package control properly  , suppose tomorrow if this external jar has another version , you could have simply updated the version details on your pom to indicate this given that this jar has a lifecycle of its own to upload newer versions to maven repositories. I encourage you to read more on repositories , and yes it is only courteous to upvote a comment if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Also @fatcook has explained in his comment about all possible  solutions  to the problem. 
External jar files can be added directly to a Java Project, but when it comes to a Maven project we need to add such third party jars as external dependency explained in the following links.

Quick solution:
(Rectify  with forward slashes)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm

OR

Detailed solution by @fatcook

http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to clear .m2 folder which contains downloaded maven dependencies. Maven can't just recognize the jars correctly sometimes, clearing cache folder or . m2 folder then updating the maven project may resolve jar errors.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still getting the same error